# Exclusive lock for concurrent hash map

Tags: java, synchronization, concurrenthashmap

A blog written at link provides exclusive synchronization on concurrent hashmap differently and say it is performance oriented: [exclusive lock for concurrent hash map](http://vanillajava.blogspot.in/2010/05/locking-concurrenthashmap-for-exclusive.html). I am confused whether it will really work while providing custom feature to concurrent hash map. Also I wonder whether it uses the same lock as ConcurrentHashMap

```
public class CMap<K, V> {
private final ConcurrentMap<K, V> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<K, V>();
private final Object[] locks = new Object[16]; {
    for(int i = 0;i<locks.length;i++) locks[i] = new Object();
}

public V put(K key, V value) {
    int hash = key.hashCode() & 0x7FFFFFFF;
    synchronized (locks[hash % locks.length]) { // allows concurrent writes.
        return map.put(key, value);
    }
}

public V get(K key) {
    return map.get(key); // concurrent reads.
}

public V putIfAbsentTheHardWay(K key, V value) {
    int hash = key.hashCode() & 0x7FFFFFFF;
    synchronized (locks[hash % locks.length]) { // supports custom operations.
        if (!map.containsKey(key))
            return map.put(key, value);
        else
            return map.get(key);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I don't understand - what is your question exactly?

Comment: I guess the question is "Is this a reasonable approach?" - I'd say NO, very strictly so!

Comment: "Would it work" depends on how you define "work". Generally speaking it seems counter-productive to use a ConcurrentHashMap, if you're going to implement your own locking mechanism anyway, just use a regular HashMap.